# WooCommerce | After logout the cart getting empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am totally new on WooCommerce, and I have a client with an "issue", that I am not sure if that is really an issue.

What he described to me, was the following scenario:

- The client comes in the web site,
- The client add some product in the cart,
- Then he goes in the cart, and he perform a login
- then the client logou, and the cart is getting empty.

So the question is, this behavior is the normal procedure for WooCommerce ? If so, is there a way to avoid the empty cart after the user is getting log ou of his account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting "clear cart on logout". Probably is enabled.

Comment: Under what page ? I have search all tha pages and I cannot find something similar ? :/

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.2.11

Comment: You need to upgrade to 2.2.3

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201747533-Cart-Empty-issue-after-upgrade-to-Woocommerce-2-2

Comment: I cannot. The site is build by another developer, that disabled tha upgrades. I supposed he did that because he modified the source code of WP/Plugins. I know that's totally wrong, but while the client want's only some fixations, it's no in my task list the upgrade. :(

Comment: Well as you can see, that was a bug that was fixed in 2.2.3